# c# -> WebConfigurationManager -> Int32.Parse -> Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
<add key="host" value="localhost" />
<add key="port" value="‎44311" />

var host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
var portString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];
var port = Int32.Parse(portString); //Exception here
```

It generates the following error:

> System.FormatException Input string was not in a correct format.

I have also tried with `Convert.ToInt32` with the exact same result. The weird thing is that If I hardcode the exact same value that is fetched from `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` everything works.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I have used code like this before and it has worked without a problem. It happens in a `async` method but since I can see that I have a value when debugging I don't think it is related. From everything I can see I'm sending a correct value. What am I missing?

Comment: Check encoding of config file, or maybe value contains illegal symbols

Comment: Delete the whole line and retype it by hand.

Comment: @Backs It is utf-8

Comment: @Ben I have never experienced this before but yes it worked.

Comment: Copy and paste your string in PowerShell: `([int] "‎44311"[0]).ToString("X")`  and voila: you'll see the invisible character, `U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Did what @Ben said and now it works. Deleted the line and retyped it by hand.

**Original:**

Got it working by setting `CultureInfo`, however I have never had to do this before.

```
var sv = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var en = new CultureInfo("en-US");

var portString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"].ToString(sv); //Works
var portString2 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"].ToString(en); //Exception
var portString3 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]; //Exception
```